# (Bildungssprachliches/fachliches) Wort für "für beide Seiten"

Tags: single-word-request

Beispiel:

> Investitionen, die für beide Seiten profitabel sind. Investitionen mit beidseitigem Nutzen.

Würde hier

> Investitionen mit bilateralem Nutzen

passen? (Wird ja normal eher für Verträge/Abkommen verwendet)

Was wären sonst noch Fachwörter, die in dem Zusammenhang *für beide Seiten* beschreiben?

Comment: Bilateral wird imo eher in der Politik verwendet. Ich würde tatsächlich eher "Investitionen zum beiderseitigen Nutzen" verwenden, das ist durchaus gängig: https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/zum+beiderseitigen+nutzen.html findet z.B. auch Texte der EU-Komission

Comment: Theoretisch könnte man *mit bipartitem Nutzen* sagen, aber das Wort *bipartit* verwendet - außer ein paar Spezln aus der Mathematik und dem Gewerkschaftswesen - kaum einer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich würde beid**er**seitigem Nutzen vorschlagen. Reziprok und mutuell scheint mir zu sehr aus dem Englischen rückübersetzt zu sein und klingt auch meiner Meinung nach unelegant.

Comment: Bildungssprachliche Ausdrücke sind für die Mehrheit der Bevölkerung unverständlich. Ob das für _»beiderseitig«_ zutrifft, bezweifle ich. – Wenn es darum ginge, das optimale Wort zu finden, wäre _»beiderseitig«_ bei weitem besser als das Zeugs in meiner Antwort, wahrscheinlich die beste Wahl. Aber der OP sucht ja nicht das optimale Wort, sonst würde er nicht eingrenzend von bildungssprachlich/Fachwort reden. So gesehen liefere ich dem OP den Dreck, den er haben will.

Answer (score 0):

Gefunden habe ich

> [mutual](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mutual) / [mutuell](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mutuell) =
>   gegenseitig, wechselseitig
>
> [reziprok](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reziprok) = wechselseitig, gegenseitig [erfolgend], aufeinander bezüglich

was im Beispiel so aussieht:

> - Investitionen mit mutualem Nutzen
> - Investitionen mit mutuellem Nutzen
> - Investitionen mit reziprokem Nutzen

wobei »reziprok« natürlich meist in der Mathematik verwendet wird und die beiden übrigen seltene Vertreter sind.

Comment: Keine der vorgeschlagenen Beispiele habe ich je so gehört oder gelesen.
Reziprok impliziert außerdem, dass genau dort, wo für die eine Seite Nutzen entsteht, für die andere keiner bestünde. Was vielleicht stimmt, aber mit beiderseitig nicht ausgesagt wird.

Comment: Ich hatte auch über *mutuell* nachgedacht, aber ich glaube, wir sitzen hier einem englischen Hokuspokus auf. Nur weil jedermann bei der Arbeit inzwischen Englisch spricht, ist *mutuell* noch kein wirklich verwendbares Wort im Deutschen. - Mein Vorschlag von *bipartit* krankt natürlich an dem gleichen Gebrechen.

Comment: Ich stimme meinen beiden Vorrednern @ChristianGeiselmann und IngoBochmann zu. Ich hatte davon abgesehen, selbst eine Antwort zu schreiben, weil sie doch sehr subjektiv wäre, aber "beiderseitig" oder "gegenseitig" wären IMHO die besten Varianten - oder aber, wenn man denn unbedingt den Zuhörern mit Fremdworten imprägnieren möchte ( ;-) ) am ehesten das schon in der Frage stehende "bilateral".

Comment: obiger Kommentar auch @IngoBochmann, aber die Software lässt nur ein At-Name zu...

Comment: "mutuell" und "reziprok" klingen für mich sehr nach Französich und Latein. Aber der Fragesteller sucht ja explizit nach etwas Bildungs-Fachsprachlichem und da geht es oft in diese Richtung.